# SQLDataReader not reading

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I am trying to make an alert system that checks a medications linked allergies with a patients linked allergies (see image below).
[image: ERD]

When I run the code it seems to just completely skip the SQLDataReader, I have performed checks on if(reader.HasRows) and it just shows there are no rows in the reader. All I want to do is show a message box with the selected allergy name at the end of the reader. I am using SQL Server 2014.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
private void button_addItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox_select_Item.Text.ToString()))
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT allergyName, allergyDescription FROM Allergies A INNER JOIN PatientAllergies PA ON A.allergyID = PA.allergyID WHERE A.allergyID = PA.allergyID AND PA.allergyID = (SELECT allergyID FROM Medication_Allergies MA WHERE MA.medID = " + comboBox_select_Item.SelectedValue.ToString() + ")", conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader();
                Allergies allergies = new Allergies();

                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    allergies.allergyName = Convert.ToString(sqlReader["allergyName"]);
                    allergies.allergyDescription = Convert.ToString(sqlReader["allergyDescription"]);
                }

                MessageBox.Show(allergies.allergyName);
                sqlReader.Close();
                FillSalesItemGrid();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the query returns zero rows.

Comment: I just dont see how, I have traced through my statement and it should return a value.

Comment: You might also be getting an error from SQL. ExecuteReader doesn't surface SQL errors as .NET exceptions. Can you grab the string you're creating and run it in SSMS?

Also, i would remiss if I didn't point out that your code is vulnerable to injection attack.

Comment: Likely not related to your problem but `MA.medID = " + comboBox_select_Item.SelectedValue.ToString() + "` really should be replaced with `MA.medID = @medID` then add a `sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue(@medID, comboBox_select_Item.SelectedValue);` on the next line to make the query parameterized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your SqlCommand is vulnerable to sql injections attack - you should always use SqlParameter as it helps you to prevent sql injections.
So your SqlCommand should looks like :

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT allergyName, allergyDescription FROM Allergies A INNER JOIN PatientAllergies PA ON A.allergyID = PA.allergyID WHERE A.allergyID = PA.allergyID AND PA.allergyID = (SELECT allergyID FROM Medication_Allergies MA WHERE MA.medID = @medID)", conn);
```

and you can pass parameter:

```
  sqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medID",comboBox_select_Item.SelectedValue);
```

What is more, following statement in your query is redundant

```
WHERE A.allergyID = PA.allergyID
```

because you have INNER JOIN on this field

```
FROM Allergies A INNER JOIN PatientAllergies PA ON A.allergyID = PA.allergyID
```

so you can remove redundant statement from your query

```
SELECT allergyName, allergyDescription FROM Allergies A INNER JOIN PatientAllergies PA ON A.allergyID = PA.allergyID WHERE PA.allergyID = (SELECT allergyID FROM Medication_Allergies MA WHERE MA.medID = @medID)
```

I'm pretty sure that rest of your code is more or less fine. Please have a look if your query returns any rows. For example you can copy your query and replace @medID with value from your comboBox.

Comment: You have actually saved my life, all works fine now. Thanks for all your help